# Docker - Mount a docker volume on separate host partition

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

My CentOS system has two partitions. Main one has 20G & other one (mounted on `/data`) has 500G. I want to mount a volume on other partition as shown below. Everything is successful but the files of partition are not being shown in container.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
vvriv:
  container_name: vvr
  image: duser/vvr
  ports:
    - "9051:80"
  volumes:
    - ./application/site:/srv/www/site
    - /data/static:/srv/www/vvstatic
  environment:
    - TERM=xterm
```

On docker container, I can see the files of `./application/site` inside `/srv/www/site` but the files `/data/static` are not being shown in `/srv/www/vvstatic`.

I don't see any visible errors. Any idea why this is happening? Is it because of the different partition?